# elastic search filter by last element in array

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some data in elastic which contains a string array field `values`. I'm trying to check if the last element in array equal to any of the given values `vs`. I tried following script, but got error `illegal_argument exception,  text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document...` Anyone can help?

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "source":"params.vs.contains(doc['values'][doc['values'].size() - 1])",
            "lang": "painless",
            "params": {
              "vs": ["a","b"]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming field values is keyword you can remove ".keyword" in query)

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "source": """
            def size = doc['values.keyword'].size();
            def last = doc['values.keyword'][size - 1];
            return params.vs.contains(last);
            """,
            "lang": "painless",
            "params": {
              "vs": ["a","b"]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This field is not specified in my mapping, so the type is auto assigned by elastic. I tried above query with ".keyword", still getting the same error

Comment: provide the mapping please

Comment: I didn't define the mapping, elastic adds this field automatically

Comment: anyway there will be the mapping of the index.  execute in devtools GET name_indice.

Comment: type: text, fields: {keyword:{type:keyword, ignore_above: 256}}

Comment: Add check null, I think some documents dont have the field values. I tested doc['values.keyword'].

Comment: Thanks a lot. Adding the null check does make the code run. But I'm seeing the values returned is in reverse order. For example what stored in db is [a,b,c], but doc['values.keyword'].get(size - 1) actually gives me 'a' instead of 'c'. Do you happen to have any idea why this happened.

Comment: Found the reason, the order is not preserved at search time.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/complex-core-fields.html#_multivalue_fields

Comment: maybe you are index data with incorrect order. Look the doc: 
When you get a document back from Elasticsearch, any arrays will be in the same order as when you indexed the document.